# How can i use Seaborn.lmplot function without naming DataFrame columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I want to use ***Seaborn.lmplot*** for scattering Dataframe's **"column 1"** vs **"column 2"** , but in according to Seaborn documentation :

> Seaborn.lmplot(x, y, data, hue=None, ...)

We should provide names of columns for using this function, in other words Dataframes columns should be strings instead of integers.

I've tried a following methods, but none of them works!

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('someData.csv',sep=',', header=None)

sns.lmplot(0,1, data= df)
sns.lmplot(df[0], df[1])
sns.lmplot("0","1",data= df)
```

and my dataFrame is something like:
[image]

Is there any method that I can use Seaborn.lmplot without naming columns!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seaborn does not allows for unnamed columns.
However, an easy solution is to rename the columns just for the purpose of plotting. Mapping the integer to a string (`lambda x: str(x)`) would allow to use strings as column names for the seaborn plot.

```
sns.lmplot(x="0", y="1", data=df.rename(columns=lambda x: str(x)))
```

The original dataframe will stay unchanged.